# FIFO позволяет двум разным приложениям получить данные друг от друга?

Tags: linux, c, fifo

Мне нужно из kernel-mode приложения получить значение переменной из user-mode приложения. Почитал про FIFO, но до конца не понял, позволяет ли этот метод получить значение переменной из другого процесса?
Я смотрел простенький пример:
main.c

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int fd;
    char * myfifo = "/tmp/myfifo";

    /* create the FIFO (named pipe) */
    mkfifo(myfifo, 0666);

    /* write "Hi" to the FIFO */
    fd = open(myfifo, O_WRONLY);
    write(fd, "Hi man!", sizeof("Hi man!"));
    close(fd);

    /* remove the FIFO */
    unlink(myfifo);

    return 0;
}
```

Чтение:
read.c

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAX_BUF 1024

int main()
{ int i;
    int fd;
    char * myfifo = "/tmp/myfifo2";
    char buf[MAX_BUF];

    /* open, read, and display the message from the FIFO */
    fd = open(myfifo, O_RDONLY);
    read(fd, buf, MAX_BUF);
    printf("Received: %s\n", buf);
    close(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

При выполнении чтения, main закрывается, но читает верно. Как мне добиться, чтобы main.c не закрывался при чтении fifo?

---

Подробности из комментария:

компилирую main.c, запускаю, он выполняется в терминале, пока не выполню read.c в другом терминале. После выполнения read.c завершает работу приложения в терминале с main.c и в терминале с read.c.

Comment: Расшифруйте, что значит "main закрывается, но читает верно"?

Comment: @zed, компилирую main.c, запускаю, он выполняется в терминале, пока не выполню read.c в другом терминале. После выполнения read.c завершает работу приложения в терминале с main.c и в терминале с read.c

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, а почему тогда main.c ждет выполнения приложения read.c?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> компилирую main.c, запускаю, он выполняется в терминале, пока не выполню read.c в другом терминале. После выполнения read.c завершает работу приложения в терминале с main.c и в терминале с read.c

то, что вы описали, и должно происходить — обе программы должны завершиться. если вам требуется иная логика работы, то её надо реализовать.

> а почему тогда main.c ждет выполнения приложения read.c?

потому что открытие «трубы» (pipe) блокирует работу процесса до тех пор, пока из «трубы» не будет произведено чтение.

см. в документации [`man mkfifo`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mkfifo.3.html):

> Opening a FIFO for reading normally blocks until some other process opens the same FIFO for writing, and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте цикл читать до определенного значения

```
for(;;){
  read(fd, buf, MAX_BUF);
  printf("Received: %s\n", buf);
  if(buf[0] == 0xff)
    break;
}
```